# How to keep Visual Studio from opening the website during publish?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

In both VS 12 and VS 13, whenever you click publish project, it will deploy to the server and then it will open it in the default browser.  This is really annoying because i have to keep closing it when it does that.  How do i keep this from happening? I just want it to publish and then stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the Destination URL setting in the publish profile (it's on the Connection tab in the Publish dialog).